# Where is SQL Server Configuration Manager in SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, configurationmanager, sql-server-2016

Where is the **SQL Server Configuration Manager** in SQL Server 2016?

It is not under the menu group for SQL Server 2016.

(I have the Developer Edition installed)

Comment: Win+R `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe /32 C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager13.msc` Run

Comment: I uninstalled it thinking something went wrong, and didn't want to redo it as the download was painfully slow

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1.Open run  <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>

2.Type below command..

```
SQLServerManager13.msc
```

sometimes SQLServer Configuration manager won't appear in search ,either due to recent installation ,so it was not indexed or some other reason..So you can use above command to open it from RUN..

Below are some more commands corresponding to different versions..

```
SQLServerManager15.msc   SQLServer2019
SQLServerManager14.msc   SQLServer2017
SQLServerManager13.msc   SQLServer2016
SQLServerManager12.msc   SQLServer2014
SQLServerManager11.msc   SQLServer2012
SQLServerManager10.msc   SQLServer2008
```

**References:**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I wonder why it was removed from the menu, it was a convenience.