# Not able to connect to local SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have just recently downloaded and installed SQL Server 2008 on my laptop. I want to login using my local details.

I tried like this in my image below

[image: img 1]

but I get this error:

[image: img 2]

Kindly let me know how to connect it as I am new for doing first time installation.

Comment: downvote should be followed by some valid reasons,

Comment: Is your server enabled?

Comment: @Sami: how to check that ?

Comment: whaht happens when you try dot `.`

Comment: Hit Win+R - Write `services.msc`- Search for yor SQL Server- run it.

Comment: @Sami: I can only see `sql vss writer` is that the only are talking about

Comment: @VVVV No, it's `SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)` by default.

Comment: @Sami then I guess I might have not installled it properly..do u have any link on how to install it properly?? May be that can fix my issue

Comment: @VVVV https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/06/12/sql-server-2008-step-by-step-installation-guide-with-images/

Comment: @Sami: in first step "set up support rules" in the screenshot it is given as 12  steps has been passed but in my set up i have total of 6 steps passed. why ?

Comment: Did you happen to download and install the **Express** edition? This would default to a `SQLEXPRESS` instance, so you'd have to use `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or  `.\SQLEXPRESS` as your server/instance name to connect

Comment: @marc_s: I downloaded the sql from https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=7593 the `_86` version. is this the correct one or give me the correct link for downloading it

Comment: @VVVV It's EXPRESS as marc say

Comment: @Sami: then where I am going wrong where it has stated 12 passed step

Comment: Actually, this is the **Management Studio** - this is ***ONLY*** the management GUI, but ***NOT*** the actual **database engine!** Of course you cannot connect  - you ***DON'T HAVE*** any database **engine** installed!

Comment: @VVVV Read [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2011/02/18/step-by-step-installing-sql-server-management-studio-2008-express-after-visual-studio-2010/)

Comment: @marc_s: so what should I do to practise sql. any simple easy stuff to install it. i m fed up on this for more than 3 hours

Comment: Download a SQL Server **Express ENGINE** - the actual database to run your queries....https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-editions-express

Comment: @Sami: i tried with that only earlier. and when I checked inside configuration manager then there was services which were empty.

Comment: @marc_s: what installation type should I select basic, custom or download media ?

Comment: Just click the big "Download Now >" button  ....

Comment: @marc_s: i m asking the process which is after that, i mean to say downloading in the installation process

Comment: @marc_s: successfully installed see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9QXe.png now what to do ?

Comment: @Sami: can u see my previous comments for more info

Comment: Now you can connect to it using the `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` server/instance name from Mgmt Studio and use it (and BTW: I'd download a more recent version of Mgmt Studio, while you're at it, and install it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms )

Comment: thanks a lot did it and its working fine..:)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons..few listed below

1. Instance name may be incorrect..So try searching for all the available instances ..when you are connecting from local ,you can check that easily by try clicking on server name drop down and browse for more and clicking database engines
2. Once instance name is correct, you can try checking if SQL Server services are running by opening [configuration manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38825056/2975396)
3. If SQL Server is running , you may want to check if network protocols are enabled in same configuration manager
4. One more reason could be SQL Server browser service not running..this helps you to connect to right instance when you have multiple instances running on same box and you don't specify port number while connecting

Comment: When I go to check the instance name, it is blank. And my sqlservices are also not running I guess.

Comment: it can't be blank, if you install sql server, can you paste browse more screenshot in your question

Comment: Sure, I have just restarted my laptop. Give me some time on how I m installing it

Answer (score 0):

Do the following to troubleshoot:

1. Go into sql server connection manager and check if sql server services is running. If it is not running then start it.
2. If it is running, right click it and open it.
3. Copy name of instance from and paste that name in management studio connection window.
4. If you still get error try connecting it with ‘.’ In server name in ssms connection window.
5. If its still not working, go in sql server connection manager and check protocols. Check if named pipe protocol is enabled. If not enabled, enable named pipe protocol.

If you follow above steps you should fix the error you are getting.