# Get all SQL Server services in my machine

Tags: sql-server

I got strange feeling that my local computer runs several versions of SQL Server. How to know all running SQL Servers on my PC?

Answer (score 2):

> How to know all running SQL servers on my PC?

Best way would be to go through configuration manager ..As per your version you can open [configuration manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38824654/where-is-sql-server-configuration-manager-in-sql-server-2016/38825056#38825056) and see all the versions of sqlserver installed.

Below is a snippet from my local machine

[image]

One more way would be to go through discovery manager,if you have installation media on your system.. you can double click the setup file and click on tools as shown below

[image]

and finally you can see all versions of sqlserver in a report like below .Distinct instance Id is the number of instances here.Opening sqlserver 2016 discovery report won't show 2017 instances,so always open with highest version

[image]